# la pantalla se queda inmóvil en Flutter desarrollo

Tags: android, flutter

tengo el siguiente problemas, por petición de cliente tengo que carga un formulario y otra información adicional en este caso es la funcion **list()**   y **dataTable** ,

El cargue de la información funciona bien

El mayor problema es que la información adicional no sube ni baja con el debo  y se queda estática y no encuentro la soluciones.

donde dice data repetidamente se crea otra pantalla inmóvil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldState,
          appBar: AppBar(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
            title: Text(
              widget.fresado == null ? "Añadir Datos" : "Editar Datos",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                  //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FutureBuilder(
                        future: list_fresadodetalle,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          return dataTable(snapshot.data);
                        }),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: Column(
                        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          //_buildTextField_users_id(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_unidad_funcional_id(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_calzada(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_longitud(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_plano_codigo(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_version(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_ancho_uno(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_ancho_dos(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_espesor_uno(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_espesor_dos(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_latitud(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_longitud_x(),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                          _buildTextField_eje(),
    
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                         
    
                          list(context),//realizo la consulta adicional 
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    _isLoading
                        ? SingleChildScrollView(child: Container())
                        : Container(),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }


//realizar la segunda consulta
Widget list(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: FutureBuilder(
      future: list_fresadodetalle,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return dataTable(snapshot.data);
        }

        if (null == snapshot.data || snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return Text("Primero deber guarda para seguir el siguiente paso");
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    )
        // ,
        //));
        );
  }



Widget dataTable(List<FresadoDetalle> profiles) {
    return Container(
      //children: [
      //  Card(

      child: StreamBuilder(
          //stream: null,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true, //Added
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            FresadoDetalle profile = profiles[index];
            return Text('data');
          },
          itemCount: profiles.length,
        );
      }),
     
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un error, ni nada solo que el `ListView` tiene el evento de detectar gestos encima, ya sea para `scroll, reload, etc`, y al tratar de hacer `scroll` está forzando la `ListView` a avanzar, pero no a `SingleScrollView`, suele pasar con las `Lista`, deverias mostarlo en uno separado o desactivar el scroll.

Se puede evitar usando `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`.

```
Widget dataTable(List<FresadoDetalle> profiles) {
    return Container(
      //children: [
      //  Card(

      child: StreamBuilder(
          //stream: null,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true, //Added
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),//Evitará a que trate de Scrolear
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            FresadoDetalle profile = profiles[index];
            return Text('data');
          },
          itemCount: profiles.length,
        );
      }),
     
    );
  }
```

ademas `SingleChildScrollView` deberia estas en el `body`

```
...
body:SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ...
),
...
```

Comment: gracias, muchas gracias me salvaste el día, tenia varios días sin solucionar el problema